# Read Inputsream twice using Jersey FormDataParam

Tags: java, stream, jersey, heap-memory, multipartform-data

Using FormaDataParam annotation twice on the different variables in jersey lets me read the content twice. Does it mean the consumer will send me data twice or It's stored in memory somewhere? I'm trying to read InputStream twice to perform two different I/O operation without storing the data in the heap

```
@POST
@Path("/new")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response saveNew(
        @FormDataParam("metada") FormDataBodyPart metadata,
        @FormDataParam("content") InputStream content,
        @FormDataParam("content") FormDataContentDisposition contentDetails,
        @FormDataParam("content") InputStream content2) throws IOException {
```

Comment: The data is already stored in the heap. It isn't sent to you twice.